# Automatically install list of packages in R if necessary

Tags: r

I would like to check, at the beginning of my R script, whether the required packages are installed and, if not, install them.

I would like to use something like the following:

```
RequiredPackages <- c("stockPortfolio","quadprog")
for (i in RequiredPackages) { #Installs packages if not yet installed
    if (!require(i)) install.packages(i)
}
```

However, this gives me error messages because R tries to install a package named 'i'. If instead I use...

```
if (!require(i)) install.packages(get(i))
```

...in the relevant line, I still get error messages.

Anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the problem has been solved by @Thomas's answer, I would like to point out that `pacman` might be a better yet simple choice:

First install pacman:

```
install.packages("pacman")
```

Then load packages. Pacman will check whether each package has been installed, and if not, will install it automatically.

```
pacman::p_load("stockPortfolio","quadprog")
```

That's it.

*Relevant links:*

1. [pacman GitHub page](https://github.com/trinker/pacman)
2. [Introduction to pacman](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pacman/vignettes/Introduction_to_pacman.html)

Comment: Thanks - I am using this now and it works very well!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is close to what you want:

```
requiredPackages <- c("stockPortfolio","quadprog")
for (package in requiredPackages) { #Installs packages if not yet installed
if (!requireNamespace(package, quietly = TRUE))
install.packages(package)
}
```

[HERE](https://rdrr.io/github/acidgenomics/acidbase/src/R/requireNamespaces.R) is the source code and an explanation of the `requireNamespace` function.

Comment: source link is not available now

Answer (score 2):

Both `library` and `require` use non-standard evaluation on their first argument by default. This makes them hard to use in programming. However, they both take a `character.only` argument (Default is `FALSE`), which you can use to achieve your result:

```
RequiredPackages <- c("stockPortfolio","quadprog")
for (i in RequiredPackages) { #Installs packages if not yet installed
    if (!require(i, character.only = TRUE)) install.packages(i)
}
```

Comment: I'd add that if you grow up from writing scripts and put your code into packages then this is all handled by the package dependency stuff and you don't end up having to write thiings like this.

Comment: Or in inside the loop : `if(! i%in% row.names(installed.packages())) install.packages(i)` if you don't want to pollute your namespace or deal with errors due to dependencies that were not declared (or if you don't want to install dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I have by now written the following function (and put it into a package), which essentially does what @Thomas and @federico propose:

```
SPLoadPackages<-function(packages){
    for(fP in packages){
        eval(parse(text="if(!require("%_%fP%_%")) install.packages('"%_%fP%_%"')"))
        eval(parse(text="library("%_%fP%_%")"))
    }
}
```